# Pandas apply method „pd.Series.max“

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

*Please update the title accordingly as I don’t know a good title for that question. I even couldn’t find a good formulation for my question to search with.*

If I call the „apply“ method on a DataFrame, my understanding is that by default, I traverse through every column. If I want to find the max value, without using the lambda function, I can go like this:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.max)
```

But I haven’t fully grasped how this method call works under the hood. Is the „pd.Series“ a wildcard for each column that gets passed in or how do I have to understand that?

Comment: Not directly the question, but you can use `df.max()`

Answer (score 0):

`df.apply` calls the specified function for each column of the dataframe (or row, if you pass `axis=1`). `pd.Series.max` is just a function in the `pd.Series` object. You could use any function, e.g. the built-in `max` function, like `df.apply(max)`.